# Вычисление градиентов в pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

Я создаю нейронку. У меня возникает проблема с пересчётом градиентов. Проблема связана с тем, что я скалярно перемножаю 2 тензора `u @ v` и делаю нормировку одного из них. Важно, что по `h` градиенты вычислять нельзя. Поэтому я использую `detach()`. Кроме того, во время пересчёта градиентов, не следует учитывать нормировку (как это сделать, я не знаю).

```
import torch
from torch import nn


class Nn(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Nn, self).__init__()
        self.ln = nn.Linear(5, 5)

    def forward(self, x):
        v = self.ln(x)

        u = v.clone()
        h = v.clone()

        u /= u.norm()
        h = h.detach()
        h /= h.norm()

        res = torch.stack([torch.stack([u @ h, u @ h])])

        return res


def patches_generator():
    while True:
        decoder = torch.rand((5, ))
        target = torch.randint(2, (1,))
        yield decoder, target


net = Nn()

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters())

net.train()
torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)
for decoder, targets in patches_generator():
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    outputs = net(decoder)
    loss = criterion(outputs, targets)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

В итоге, я получаю следующую ошибку:

> RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has
>   been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.FloatTensor [9, 512, 1,
>   1]], which is output 0 of ReluBackward1, is at version 3; expected
>   version 2 instead. Hint: the backtrace further above shows the
>   operation that failed to compute its gradient. The variable in
>   question was changed in there or anywhere later. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autograd не умеет работать со случаями когда `input` для операции меняется. In-place можно делать `x += 1`, а вот делать `x += что_зависит_от_x`.

https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/encounter-the-runtimeerror-one-of-the-variables-needed-for-gradient-computation-has-been-modified-by-an-inplace-operation/836/5